# Debugging client-side script in Glimpse

Tags: glimpse

I have installed Glimpse debugging and diagnostic tool in my Visual Studio. And I need to debug the the client-side script in Glimpse.Is this possible?If it is, what is the extension that needs to be installed?

Comment: do you have an idea about this? @cgijbels

Comment: So are you trying to debug a problem with the "Glimpse.js" itself? Or you have a different script that you or someone else you wrote and need to debug?

Comment: we have our own script that needs to be debug

Comment: It's best to use the F12 tools built into your browser for that.